# How to identify distinct objects in image in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to identify separate objects in an image in OpenCV. So far I've opened the image into a NumPy array and thresholded it so it is binary. Here's what it looks like:

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9CXB.png)

I'm trying to identify the NumPy array indices where different objects are for instance segmentation. Here is what I am trying to achieve: 
 [End goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB6Mg.png) (I didn't bother coloring every single object in this image with a different color but you get the idea)

Essentially, I'm trying to label every cluster of pixels considered an 'object' as a separate class and generate a list of array indices for each of these classes. I've tried using OpenCV's connectedComponentsWithStats, but I have no idea how to generate a list of array indices for the locations of each object in this image. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (good) questions around here. Please provide a [mre] to your _specific_ problem. Please show any relevant code, and provide an actual input image, not some pre-processed one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one you are facing is [connected component labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) so the best function you can use is exactly the `connectedComponentsWithStats` you mention.

However, its use can be a bit confusing at the beginning. Here you find a working example.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image in grayscale
input_image = cv2.imread(r"satellite.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Threshold your image to make sure that is binary
thresh_type = cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU
_, binary_image = cv2.threshold(input_image, 0, 255, thresh_type)

# Perform connected component labeling
n_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(binary_image,
                                                                      connectivity=4)

# Create false color image
colors = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(n_labels , 3), dtype=np.uint8)
colors[0] = [0, 0, 0]  # for cosmetic reason we want the background black
false_colors = colors[labels]

cv2.imshow('binary', binary_image)
cv2.imshow('false_colors', false_colors)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Binary image:**

[image: binary image]

**Image labeled (in false colors):**

[image: labeled image]

The `centroids` variable already contain the centroid (x, y) coordinates of each labeled object.

```py
false_colors_draw = false_colors.copy()
for centroid in centroids:
    cv2.drawMarker(false_colors_draw, (int(centroid[0]), int(centroid[1])),
                   color=(255, 255, 255), markerType=cv2.MARKER_CROSS)
cv2.imshow('false_colors_centroids', false_colors_draw)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Centroids:**

[image: centroids image]

As you can see, they are quite a lot. If you want to keep only the bigger objects, you can either i) use morphological operations on your binary image in the beginning or ii) use the area information which is already contained in `stats`.

```py
MIN_AREA = 50
false_colors_draw = false_colors.copy()
for i, centroid in enumerate(centroids[1:], start=1):
    area = stats[i, 4]
    if area > min_area:
        cv2.drawMarker(false_colors_draw, (int(centroid[0]), int(centroid[1])),
                       color=(255, 255, 255), markerType=cv2.MARKER_CROSS)
```

**Centroids (filtered by area):**

[image: centroid image filtered]

Comment: Where are the indices of each "label" stored? In the label array? Is each item in the labels an array representing the shape of each label?

Comment: The `label` array is an indexed image in which each pixel has a value equals to its label. E.g. if a certain blob has value 1 and another one has value 34, it means the two objects are not connected

Comment: Do you know of any simple way to extract each label as its own binary array? The images I'm working with are 12000 x 10000 so np.where isn't particularly efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cv2.findContours` and `cv2.drawContours`

[image]

Edite : code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random as rng

im = cv2.imread('YourImagePath\\test2.png')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 113, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = 
cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
idx =0

for cnt in contours:
    idx += 1
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    roi=im[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    color = (rng.randint(0, 256), rng.randint(0, 256), rng.randint(0, 256))
    #cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),color,2)
    cv2.drawContours(im,[cnt],0 ,color,-1)
cv2.imshow('img',im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: please, include the source code as text, not as a picture.